# How to add subscript to ggplot axis title when title starts with bracket symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols, axis-labels, x-axis

I've looked on SO and haven't found this exact issue or solution for this.
I am trying to label my x-axis: [NO3 + NO2] (mu mol L ^-1); where the 3 and 2 are subscripts, the mu shows as the symbol and the -1 is a superscript.

[image: x-axis label that I want]

I think my main issue right now is that my x-axis title has to start with the "[" bracket.
I am using ggplot.

I am able to get the first part "[NO3" but haven't been able to add anything past the subscripted 3:

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]))
```

Can't seem to add anything after the 3 without getting errors

I've tried the following:

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3] '+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3] '+ NO'"
```

and

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~ '+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~ '+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('"
```

and

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~ ~'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~ ~'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('"
```

and

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]'+ NO'"
```

and

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]}~'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected '}' in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]}"
```

and

```
xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('))

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  #xlab(bquote([NO[3] + NO [2]]))
  xlab(bquote('[NO'* "" [3]~'+ NO' * "" [2] '] ('"
```

and variations of...

```
labs(x = expression([NO[3]]))
```

Nothing seems to work...
Any suggestions?

Additionally, any way of splitting y-axis into three lines?
I was able to get what I want for y-axis title, which I have as:

```
ylab(bquote('\u03b1 '^{"chla"}~'\n(g C g chla'^{"-1"}~'hr'^{"-1"}~'/ ' *mu~ 'mol quanta' ~m^{"-2"}~'s'^{"-1"}~')'))
```

[image: y-axis title]

Is it possible to split this into 3 lines (the \n doesn't seem to do anything here)?

Thank you.

Comment: `xlab(bquote('[NO'[3] *'+'* 'NO'[2] * ']'*'(' *mu*'mol L' ^{"-1"} * ')' ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it this way:

Using `atop` we could stack the 3 parts of the y label.

With `expression` we specify the text of the label for x:

The first part of the label is `[NO[3]]+NO[2]` with a subscripted 3 and 2, the second part of the label is `(mu mol L^-1)` with the mu symbol and a superscripted -1:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(atop('α' ^{"chla"} ~'', atop((g*C*g*chla^{"-1"}~hr^{"-1"}), '*mu~mol~quanta~m^{"-2"}~s^{"-1"}~'))))+
  xlab(expression(atop("[NO"[3]*"+"*NO[2]*"]"*(mu*"mol L"^-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow...simple and worked perfectly... thank you! What does "atop" mean/do ?

Comment: Please check the update. Now the second part should be also answer to give y label in 3 rows. For this `atop` function is very handy.